# How to solve $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} (1+\frac 1x)^x$

Tags: infinity

I have this problem: $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} (1+\frac 1x)^x$
I understand everything except how to handle the $\pm \infty$. When I tried to solve it I reasoned like this, since both $1^\infty$ and $1^{-\infty}$ should be equal to one then the answer to the original question should be $1$. But the correct answer is $e$. I can solve problems like these when it's just $+\infty$ but how do I solve it when there is plus minus infinity? Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: " I can solve problems like these when it's just $+\infty$" : are you sure ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes Edit: Well maybe not, is there a difference between positive infinity and just infinity?

Comment: Please provide feedback if youre going to downvote the post. What can I improve etc.

Comment: @Sembfi No, this is not the point, the fact is that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$ and if you think that the limit is $1$, you have to rethink about it.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, you are right. After reading more about this, I realized that I was completely wrong.